# Regenerate the salesforce custom object in Illuminate Cloud

Tags: custom-object, sobject, ide, object, illuminatedcloud

How could I regenerate the salesforce custom object in Illuminate Cloud?

I need to do that because there are some fields which were added to the object after it was generated by the Illuminate Cloud. And now when I am trying to access these fields in my ide I am not able to do that.

I really can not find the way to do that. The only thing which I was able to come up with is to google: `regenerate salesforce custom object with illuminate cloud`. And the result got me nowhere.

Comment: The product owner of Illuminated Cloud is excellent at answering your questions on his support forums: http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/support

Comment: You need to regenerate the offline symbol table then reload the project

Comment: @Eric, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eric said, regenerate the offline symbol table. Either from the menu under `Tools->Illuminated Cloud->Regenerate Offline Symbol Table...`, or by pressing the bar-chart-looking button here: [image: Illuminated Cloud toolbar]

It then asks you if you want to do a full regeneration or just the sObjects. Just the sObjects is quicker if you've just added a field or custom object. You might need the full one if you want to reference a newly installed managed package.